# Read from csv and check the ip address reachability

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading the IP addresses from a CSV and then check if the IP addresses are reachable store the IP addresses in the list, please advise what is it that I am doing here is wrong?

```
addr = []

def ip_reachable(addr):
    result = subprocess.run(f"ping -n 3 -w 1 {addr}", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    if result.returncode == 0:
        return result.returncode, addr


with open("test.csv") as file_name:
    read_csv_file = csv.DictReader(file_name)
    for index_col in read_csv_file:
        if ip_reachable(index_col["column_1"]):
            addr.append(ip_reachable)



print(addr)
```

Comment: What does this program output currently? Any error? Empty list?

Comment: [<function ip_reachable at 0x000001A0F90CC1E0>, <function ip_reachable at 0x000001A0F90CC1E0>] is the current output

Comment: it's because your code is appending the function itself to the list and not the addr value. Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```py
addr.append(ip_reachable)
```

Try this:

```py
addr.append(index_col['column_1'])
```

I believe you want to store the address itself i.e. in `column1` and not the method `ip_reachable`.